# wordpress basic loop issues

Tags: wordpress

Im having a problem where for some reason, a basic loop im trying to add to a sidebar keeps....keeps looping on interior pages (single and page .php ) but not on index.php.

on index.php (home page) is fine.

for example, i wanted the loop to populate an unordered lists line items, so i went about it like this:

```
      <div id="sideBarMain">
        <h2>title4sidebar</h2>
       <ul>     
             <?php 
            query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'left_sidebar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby=menu_order' ) );
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>

      </div><!-- sidebar ender -->
```

A few things are happening. 
1. the MOST problematic is that when this loop is in place, it breaks the navigation and all. i click on a page and the page loads up with one of the list line items on the header...so if i click "about us" on the main nav, a page loads with "line item title" instead.....

also happens on any item clicked.

2 - is that on the (page/single.php pages), on the sidebar, it will post the first 4 posts with the category "left_sidebar" how it should be displayed, css in place and all but after the fourth line item, it will repeat the loops one more time.

3 - My sites content area has 2 columns, the sidebar on the left, and the main content area on the middle. On the part that's being wrongfully repeated (after the loops repeats), when i checked with FireBug, on the repeated line items, its also taking the H tag properties from i assume, an h-tag thats next to it on another column. So the first 4 line-items come out fine with the styles given to them via CSS, link colors, rollovers etc, and the next buggy 4 line items come out un-styled, permalink also isnt being applied to them like the first 4 etc.

3 - i removed all html from that php loop like the divs and ul / lis etc so no css is being applied, this way only text come up from the loop but the same thing happens, Since i removed the html portion of the loop, the first 4 li's come up with the standard default blue link text etc, and the following buggy 4 come up the same as before all big with htags attached....

Troubleshooting it all,
- theres only one loop on the page which stems from the sidebar.
- ive properly cleared all floats
- when checking on W3C for errors etc, there are none. green lights through and through.
- no errors on the php side of things. (ive checked every page and have errors enabled) on local server.

im lost.

Any ideas as to what can be happening?

NOTE: thinking ahead, although there is one loop ONLY on the sidebar.php page, once imported technically theres 2 loops which i guess is the sidebar wp loop, and the page.php / single.php loops which get the content.

is there anything different as of the latest wp maybe? Ive always done it like this and now i have problems......

any ideas? im lost.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/84336, please check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold:

1) **It is imperitive you stop using query_posts**. There are many well-documented reasons as to why using this function needs to end, but I think [this is the best explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

2) You aren't resetting your query. More on that in a minute.

Going back to number 1, the problem with query_posts is that it affects the global $wp_query object. This would be fine if your intention was to modify the main loop, but that's not what you're trying to do here. What you need to use is [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). The syntax in creating a new Query Object is identical to query_posts, but the benefit is that you are no longer affecting the global instance of $wp_query.

Resetting your query also ensures that no other sections of code utilizing a Wordpress Query are going to be affected by your Query Object.

Try changing your code example to this:

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query(array('category_name'=>'left_sidebar','posts_per_page'=>4,'orderby=menu_order'));
if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile;endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer and great link to the Wordpress Stackexchange thread, 1st time I've seen that. That's such a good answer I can even pretend the flowchart hasn't been done in Comic sans :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be some filters in your functions.php that interact with these functions. Take a look there and see if you want find something.

You should also try using `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before and after your loop, so you make sure that it doesn't interact with the others.